# Download window with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, html-select

How to get a download box for the following code. i.e., when user clicks on download hyperlink the download window should appear irrespective of the browser type. I have tried the following:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="download_tagged_file('{{cnt.id}}');">Download</a><
```

```
function download_tagged_file(cntid)
{
  var snddata = {};
  snddata["cntid"] = cntid;
  $.post("/tagging/download_tagged_file/", snddata, 
     function callbackHandler(data, textstatus) 
     {
        if (data.status == 1)
        {
            var url = data.filename;
            url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000" + url
           //var htm = '<iframe style="display: none;" id="if1" src="'+url+'"></iframe>';
           //alert(url);
           window.open(url, 'download_window', 'directories=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizeable=0,width=1,height=1,top=0,left=0');
           window.focus();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I don't really get what youre trying to do, whats wrong with:</strike>

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{cnt.id}}">Download</a>
```

**Update:**

you need to control the content disposition server-side. The above html is what you need, but your server needs to send this header when serving the file:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>
```

Comment: Your code will open another window right with the file.How to get download dialog box with save as option....Something to so with content disposition

Comment: Since i am generating the file on the fly is it proper to add the content -sisposition on AJAX call